# c# linq return records by cells - indexer and Value

Tags: c#, linq, indexer

i struggle figuering out a solution for the following Task.

Setup:

```
class Records
{

    Cells cells;

}

class Cell
{

    string FieldName;
    string Value;

}

class Cells : Collection<Cell>
{

    public Cell this[string FieldName]

}

list<Records> records;
```

Program:
new Records are added into "records", each record contains same Setup of cells.

Goal:
a linq-command that will return a list of all records, where cell-FieldName matches with search-criteria

```
like: 'select records from records where cells["ItemID"] == "ItemNo"'
```

Could you please help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: If this is homework where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be code of your indexer.

```
public Cell this[string fieldName]
    {
        get
        {
            return records.Where(t=>t.FieldName == fieldName).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```